# magento 2 Белый экран

Tags: php, magento

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой. Magento 2 выводи мне белый экран, без блоков. Почему - не знаю. Чистил кэш и т.п, но серавно проблема не уходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

И смотрите что вызывает ошибку

Comment: pub/index.php' not found or unable to stat, но не знаю из-за чего.

Comment: Уверен что в папке pub есть index.php?

Comment: Нету. Но его там и не было и всё работало.
Добавил для теста только что - серавно не работает.(Взял файл с https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.2-develop/pub)